# Typecast or call functor into a function pointer?

Tags: c++

I have code that expects a function like `test`. A 3rd party expect it to be like test2. Using the code below I can assigned the function `test` to `fn1` and `fn3rdParty` but I don't know how to make `fn1` work with `fn3rdParty`

Error

> error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from 'std::function' to 'void *(__cdecl *)(void *)'

Code

```
class Data {};
void*test(Data*data) { return 0; }
void*test2(void*data) { return 0; }

function<void*(Data*)> fn1 = test;
void*(*fn3rdParty)(void*) = test2;
fn3rdParty = (void*(*)(void*))test;
fn3rdParty = (void*(*)(void*))fn1;//error
```

Comment: There must be a better way to do this... ;)

Answer (score 0):

> but I don't know how to make fn1 work with fn3rdParty

Try this:

```
// this is outside your code's scope, as a
// local function (eventually placed in a namespace)
void adapt_fn1(void* data) { return fn1( reinterpret_cast<Data*>(data); }

// client code:
fn3rdParty = adapt_fn1;
```

That said, if you can adapt the server code (the one that imposes the function like "test") to expect a `std::function<void()>` instead, you will be able to plug anything into that (and if you do not have a matching signature in the client code, you can just use a lambda passed into the `std::function<void(void)>`).

Comment: Well I can make fn1 and data into a `pair*` and pass it into an adapt function which calls the functor with the argument but thats an extra function call and extra data wrap. Your code is a bit incorrect because fn1 is a local function variable thus cannot be access inside that function unless i put it in a global variable which i dont want to do thus the extra wrap

Comment: Have a look at std::bind as an alternative (it creates a functor with bound arguments). The problem with it is you would still need your server interface written in terms of `std::function`.